# What's wrong of my permission settings in G-WAN v7.12.2 - cannot visit the pages in www, but scripts in csp ok

Tags: g-wan

My file permission setting as following:

All files and directories `rwxrwxr-x kklou kklou`, including `www` and `csp` having the same settings, but only the scripts in `csp` can be visited.

I did study the page http://gwan.com/faq#404, but still can't solve my problem.

I tried `chmod -R 2770` of all files, but didn't work.

I tried `sudo ./gwan -d:kklou:kklou` also, still didn't work.

What can I do next? Anyone has same problem of mine?

`data-www`is in groups of `kklou` and `root`.
`root` is in groups of `kklou` and `data-www`.
`kklou` is in groups of `data-www` and `root`.
file permission of `/tmp` is `drwxrwxrwt root root`

**EDIT:** I was using port: 8080. When I change to port: 80, problem gone, pages in www CAN be shown up in my browser.

When I change back to port: 8080, problem come back, i.e. the pages in www 404 not found.

Both case are using `sudo ./gwan -d:kklou:kklou`

Answer (score 0):

Linux permissions can be difficult to follow because of the many different features like the [setuid bit](http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Security/Quick_and_Dirty_Guide_to_Linux_File_Permissions), [hierarchical permissions](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/linux_unix/article.php/3838296/How-to-Cope-with-File-Server-Permissions-Hell.htm), or SELinux.

To disable SELINUX, `/etc/selinux/config` should list: `SELINUX=disabled`

This is a system configuration issue, not a G-WAN issue.